# problem in delete from pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot

i have a problem in delete an order:

here the form where press on cancel to delete the order:

```
<form action="{{route('user.orders.delete', $order->id)}}" method="POST"
                                  onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
                                @method('DELETE')
                                @csrf
                                <button
                                    type="submit" class="mt-8 mb-4 py-2 px-14 rounded-full
                                    bg-red-900 text-white tracking-widest hover:bg-blue-800
                                    transition duration-200">
                                    Cancel
                                </button>
                            </form>
```

this is my router:

```
 Route::delete('user/orders/delete/{order}', [OrderController::class, 'delete'])->name('user.orders.delete');
```

- OrderController : delete function:

  public function delete(Order $order)
  {
  try {
  unlink(public_path().'/storage/orders/files/'.$order->file);
  $order->delete();
  }catch(\Exception $e) {
  return redirect()->back()-with('status', 'you cannot delete this item');

  ```
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'product deleted succefully');
    }
  ```

so when click on the button (cancel) just go to the right url : when 21 is the order id

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/orders/delete/21
```

and it is just not found page!!! and nothing deleted!!!

Comment: So in the network tab the delete request is 404 not found?

Comment: yes right......

Comment: It is a delete request and does php artisan route list show on the route in question

Answer (score 0):

i think your app routes is cached

try to run the fallowing command (in cmd or terminal) to see all the routes, this will show registered routes and errors if exist:

```
php artisan route:list
```

if the route doesnt exist in route list, the route list may be cached. try the fallowing command to clear route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and then run app and test the route.

If you do not have another problem in coding or naming variables, the program will be fixed properly

*if all o the above is ok, it seems your apache config  is not configure to delete request(for route delete method ) and you must change .htaccess requests LIMIT like the fallowing sample to Grant delete request :

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

As you can see the DELETE method(request) has been added to .htaccess

Comment: the route is exist, i am really wondering..... in other page i have exactly same thing and it does work....  just the differnce is i used .Route::resource instead of Route::delete !!

Comment: @OsamaMohammed So  the problem is probably from the web server .. See the updated answer